# How to share Internet from Android via Ethernet

Tags: tethering

The Situation: I've got Android running on my Cubietruck. Now I want to share the existing Internet Connection (Wifi) with my Win8 Desktop PC over Ethernet, so the stream would be

Internet –wifi→ Cubie –ethernet→ PC

I just found a thousend tutorials about making this the other way round. Is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: @Izzy Yes, thats right. So the stream would be Internet --wifi-> Cubie --ethernet-> PC.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `iptables`. You can find more about theme here - definitely take a look into `simple usage example`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

The only one problem is that iptables binary isn't really built-in into Android.
But hey, they came up with solution already http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=444004

So you can even use the example from Ubuntu help now!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I "THINK" you can do because I was thinking the same thing.

You need an wifi extender with ethernet port connection.

send your phone's hotpot data to the wifi extender then connect to your router than you can do anything you want. Hope this work!!

Comment: A phone can't receive and send WiFi at the same time I think. But if the WiFi router/extender receives the signal it can share it on ethernet and WiFI. So then a phone can pick up WiFi while PC ethernet.

Comment: @Emil some can do both like me Samsung Galaxy S8, but there aren't many with that capability

Comment: Wow, with stock rom? That's pretty cool. I've never seen a non-dedicated device that could be even "hacked" to do this. So in other words you can setup your phone as a WiFi repeater meanwhile using the phone itself to browse internet?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to use your Android device as a wifi receiver.

#### Android setting

Some Android roms have a setting that allows for sharing the internet via USB. This setting doesn't care where the internet is coming from, even though the setting is usually in the "tethering" menu, if you are connected to WiFi, it will share the wifi with whatever is connected to the "USB" port, even if it is an Ethernet dongle.

#### PDA.net APP

**PDA.net** (Also known as the companion app [foxfi](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) which still works on legacy devices) is a good choice. But that requires an app to be installed on your other device before you can use it. I use it all the time to give my PC internet from my android phone.

Your other option is to use software that shares the internet across the USB port via ADB.

#### Gnirehtet

This free open source [project called (**gnirehtet**)](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) will allow you to do all kinds of tethering of your android phone to a **Mac**, **Linux** or **Windows** computer! The minimum version of android is 5.0 (Lollipop)

[image]